# Calling a service within a forEach loop and waiting for it to finish before proceding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get the results of service calls nested in a forEach loop before executing the next block of code

I've tried using a plain for loop, that works... but ESLINT moans about it.. so what's the ideal solution?

```
const people = []

const fetchPeople = async () => {
  peopleIds.forEach(personId => {
    people.push(restApi.getPersonById(personId))
  })
}

await fetchPeople()
logger.error(`people should be populated : ${JSON.stringify(people)}`)
```

I expect people to be populated by the end of the forEach so I can use the results in the next function.

Actually, people is not populated

Comment: There's no `await` in your `async`, so it's not going to wait for the call to end. You can also use `Promise.all()`, that will keep the order of the promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is with Promise.all() and array.map()

```
const people = await Promise.all(peopleIds.map(restApi.getPersonById));
logger.error(`people should be populated : ${JSON.stringify(people)}`)
```

Array.map() will create a promise for each of the ids, Promise.all will wait for all of them and output an array of their async returned values.